# Unity WebGL Build Error - UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe did not run properly

Tags: build-error, unity-webgl

I'm using Unity 5.3.0.

I'm getting 3 errors when I build project for WebGL. UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe did not run properly

How can I solve this problem? Thanks

PS. Please take a look to screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by deleting SSAA plugin (in my case)